# kill an ActionView (Web browser) in the Android stack of my application

Tags: android, android-activity, webview, kill, actionview

I need to call a ActionView in my application. But after used it, I would like to kill it of my stack (if I press return,I don't want to come back in this view). How can I do?

Here how I call the actionView:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(liToken.getAuthorizationUrl()));
        startActivity(i);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898886/removing-an-activity-from-the-history-stack) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992812/android-how-do-i-totally-remove-an-activity-from-the-activity-stack) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001882/how-to-clear-specific-activity-from-the-stack-history), then consider closing your question.

Comment: My question is not for an Activity but for an ActionView (please read question before answer). I tried to set the intent with NO_HISTORY but it didn't work.

Comment: So then, be a little more specific about *what* you're actually trying to achieve. - You start a new Activity and, when the user presses "back" in that activity, you want what to happen? And could you explain what an *ActionView* would be?

Comment: I pass by the browser to link social networks account (authentification and come back in my application). When the user presses "back", there is the page in browser. Is there any way to finish() this webview as an activity?

Comment: So you want to intercept the "back" button inside the browser so it returns to your Activity instead of going back in the browser's history? - I doubt that's possible. A [WebView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html) gives you more control about what the user can do, so why not take a look at that.

Comment: Not the back button on the browser. I just want to delete the webbrowser of the android stack because right now the stack is: activity1, Activity2, webbrowser, Activity3. I want Activity1, Activity2, Activity3. I need to find a way to finish() the browser page. I tried to set up the intent with NO_HISTORY, that doesn't work.